# Python 3.x fill missing NaN values with the mode

Tags: python, pandas

I have programmed the following dataframe in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    x=pd.DataFrame(np.array([10,"worker","France",
                             20,"eng","Italy",
                             30,"doctor","Spain",
                             40,"eng","EEUU",
                             60,"eng",np.NaN,
                             60,"worker","France"]).reshape(6,3))
    x.columns=["age","job","country"]
    x["country"]=x["country"].fillna(x["country"].mode().iloc[0])
    print (x)
```

I would like to replace the NaN values of the country column with the mode of that column. I have tried different methods, but still prints the same values. What am I missing? I am using Python 3.7.

Thanks

Comment: looks like `np.nan` returns the string `'nan'` and so it is not recognized as `NaN`. Your code should work fine if your dataframe has `NaN` values.

Comment: I did initialize your example dataframe using a different notation `pd.DataFrame([[10,"worker","France"], [20,"eng","Italy"],...,[60,"eng",np.nan],..])` and it worked. Looks like np.nan shows odd behavior sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting the string representation of np.NaN.  fillna is not working as you expected.

use this:

```
x['country'].replace('nan',np.nan).fillna(x['country'].mode()[0])
```

or

```
x['country'].mask(x['country']=='nan').fillna(x['country'].mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
0    France
1     Italy
2     Spain
3      EEUU
4    France
5    France
Name: country, dtype: object
```